# Will LINQ use specialized/optimized versions of functions based on the type of the input?

Tags: c#, linq, collections

If I do the something like the following with LINQ:

```
void DoSomeStuffWithHashSet()
{
  HashSet<int> set = new HashSet<int>();
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) set.Add(i);
  if (Lookup(set, new Random().NextInt(200))
     System.Console.WriteLine("Yey");
  else
     System.Console.WriteLine("Ney");
}

bool Lookup(IEnumerable<int> haystack, int needle)
{
  // O(N) search or HashSet<int>.Contains()?
  return Enumerable.Contains(collection, needle);
}
```

Will `Enumerable.Contains()` resolve to the optimized implementation on `HashSet` or will a simple search be performed regardless of the input?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it will use `HashSet<T>.Contains`. `HashSet<T>` implements `ICollection<T>` and per the [documentation for `Enumerable.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880.aspx):

> If the type of source implements `ICollection<T>`, the `Contains` method in that implementation is invoked to obtain the result. Otherwise, this method determines whether source contains the specified element.

always, Always, ALWAYS check the documentation!

Comment: Note that this means `Contains` with no equality comparer is *not* the same as calling `Contains` with the default equality comparer for the key type. It's a confusing bit of API, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does - in some cases. *Not* always when you think it might be able to though.

As part of writing Edulinq, I wrote two posts ([part 40](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/26/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-40-optimization.aspx); [part 42](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/31/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-42-more-optimization.aspx)) on optimization. Basically what counts as a valid optimization isn't always obvious - but there are definitely plenty of cases where LINQ to Object optimizes based on the execution-time type of the collection. This is *mostly* the case for methods returning a single value rather than a sequence.

Answer (score 0):

It calls an `IEqualityComparer<T>` which eventually calls `Object.Equals` which itself uses a `HashSet`

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question, I'm afraid. Either that, or you're not explaining your answer very clearly.